# least cpu-expensive way to find the two most (and least) remote vertices of a graph [igraph]

Tags: python, igraph, shortest-path

In igraph, what's the least cpu-expensive way to find:

- the two most remote vertices (in term of shortest distances form one another) of a graph. Unlike the *farthest.points()* function, which chooses the first found pair of vertices with the longest shortest distance if more than one pair exists, I'd like to randomly select this pair.
- same thing with the closest vertices of a graph.

Thanks!

Comment: You might need to be more precise about what it means for a vertext to be "most remote" - is it the farthest from *any* other vertex? Or the farthest from *all* other vertices? Or the vertex that has the farthest distance to any single other vertex? Or remote in the sense of farthest removed from any clustering of vertices based on some other criteria?

Comment: When all shortest distances in a graph are computed, what I'm looking for in the first bullet point of my question is the two vertices that are at the extremities of the longest of these shortest paths. For this, I could use the farthest.points() function, except it gives the first result found when several longest paths have the same shortest distance, while I need to have the algorithm to pick among the longest shortest paths randomly. I hope I'm making a little more sense... :)

Answer (score 2):

For the first question, you can find all shortest paths, and then choose between the pairs making up the longest distances.

I don't really understand the second question. If you are searching for unweighted paths, then every pair of vertices at both ends of an edge have the minimum distance (1). That is, if you don't consider paths to the vertices themselves, these have length zero, by definition.